# Qt - creating QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, paintevent

I'm trying to rewrite method `paintEvent` in my programm and change it.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QRegion reg = this->bgPixmapHandle->rect();
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setClipRegion(reg);
    painter.drawImage(bgPixmapHandle->rect(), bgPixmapHandle);
    painter.end();
}
```

Here I try to change my `bg` image. But I got an error on line: `QPainter painter(this);`

> Error: Variable 'QPainter painter' is
>   initialized, though the type is
>   incomplete

Comment: you should also know that painter.end() is not needed in this case. When the painter goes out of scope its destructor does this automatically for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include QPainter header file. QPainter class is only forward declared in one of the Qt headers you're including in that translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <QPainter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you including ?  Qt is a big fan of forward declaration of classes, which causes  such cryptic errors.